# How to upload big files to Google Cloud Storage from a Java GAE instance

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I would like to know if there is a way to upload a big file (*>500MB*) tp **Google Cloud Storage** passing through a Google App Engine application: I suppose that it is not possible because of the GAE servlet limitation (execution time <=60s).

Is it correct or do you know some new trick?

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean by "passing through" an application?

You can use createUploadUrl and set a destination Google Storage bucket in the [UploadOptions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/UploadOptions.html) and the blob will be written to Google storage rather than blobstore, and your callback will be invoked when the upload is complete.

Answer (score 1):

When you upload a file, it's between your client and the Cloud Storage. There should be no request to your front-end instance hanging until the upload is complete.

That being said, if for some reason your front-end should get involved as a "pass-through" link, there is no limit on a servlet that runs on the backend instance. You can link your upload widget to your backend instance, i.e. call myBackend1.myApp.appspot.com. You can read on how to configure the backend in GAE documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply: it's clear. My doubt was the following: if I create a GUI, using for example GWT, needed to allow user uploading a file into Google Cloud Storage (it will be a new feature of an existing application) what happened to GAE instance if the user will upload a big file? I understood that there is no problem and the RPC will not return an exception caused by time limit. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Google Cloud Storage's direct upload mechanism:

https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-methods#postobject

Did you already consider that as an option?